# Nginx proxy_pass when http referer contains a string?

Tags: nginx

I test the config below, not work. How to make it?

```
http {

    server {
        location / {
            if ($http_referer ~* /.*/flee.*/) {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8765;
            }
        }
    }

}
```